# Cron Job: Redirecting shell script output to a file

Tags: bash, shell, cron

Just an one line shell script below not working as a cron job but executing directly from terminal works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Executed" >> ./crond.log 2>&1
```

What might be the problem?

Checked /var/log/cron and found cron is kicking the task in time:

```
May 16 10:30:01 vagrant-centos64 CROND[3015]: (root) CMD (sh /vagrant/my.sh)
May 16 10:35:01 vagrant-centos64 CROND[3122]: (root) CMD (sh /vagrant/my.sh)
May 16 10:40:01 vagrant-centos64 CROND[3189]: (root) CMD (sh /vagrant/my.sh)
May 16 10:45:01 vagrant-centos64 CROND[3270]: (root) CMD (sh /vagrant/my.sh)
May 16 10:50:01 vagrant-centos64 CROND[3343]: (root) CMD (sh /vagrant/my.sh)
May 16 10:55:01 vagrant-centos64 CROND[3430]: (root) CMD (sh /vagrant/my.sh)
```

Crontab job listing is like below:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /vagrant/mypagelogin.sh
*/5 * * * * sh /vagrant/my.sh
[root@vagrant-centos64 vagrant]#
```

Access permission for crond.log is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 0 May 16 10:51 crond.log
```

UPDATE: crond.log file is located in the same location as my.sh. [/vagrant]

Comment: Define _not working_

Comment: Where is your crond.log? (I'd advise against making the assumption that your cron job is started from the user's home directory.)

Comment: I don't see any question. Is your question where is `crond.log` or why the permission is like that or anything else?

Comment: Updated question according to above question

Comment: I was looking for the cause why the file crond.log is not written to from the script if it is executed as a cron job?

Comment: what @UlrichSchwarz said.  especially when it's a root cron job, not a vagrant cron job.

Comment: Ah..it is a root cron job of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First rule of `crond` club: you don't assume the working directory. My guess is that you'll find a `crond.log` in `/root`. If you want it in `/vagrant`, explicitly redirect the output to `/vagrant/crond.log`.

(FWIW, the second rule of `crond`club is: don't assume there's anything in your `PATH`, use explicit paths to binaries, but since `echo` is also a bash builtin, you're fine on that one.)

Comment: also put the job in vagrant's crontab, not root's **unless** there is a particular need for the job to run as root.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. I just put the absolute path for the cornd.log file as /vagrant/crond.log.

Answer (score 1):

It's written but not where you're looking for. The best way is using absolute paths.

Comment: Nice advice. I wii try it and update. Thank you.